# Need detail explanation of Bluetooth command "hcitool con" and hcitool sr

Tags: bluetooth, hci

**ISSUE :** To switch master/slave role between the devices.

I am trying hard to switch role between bluetooth devices but with no luck.

I know there is **"hcitool sr "** command which switch role for us but everytime i type this command after  establishing connection I got  the error shown below...

```
 command -> hcitool sr DC:A9:71:8D:2D:C6 m
```

***Switch role request failed: Input/output error***

I have typed  'm' or 's' or full name like master or slave but with no success and also I have typed this command when pairing has been successful and connection has been established.

To verify connection I type following command 
**hcitool con**

**o/p :**

Connections:

> ACL DC:A9:71:8D:2D:C6 handle 43 state 1 lm SLAVE AUTH ENCRYPT

what does this mean ? Can soemone please explain me specially "SLAVE" part.
What I think of this output is that my in-house device hci0  is connected with mac-address of  DC:A9:71:8D:2D:C6 via ACL link  and my in-house device is SLAVE. Am I right ?

Also I have  noticed that when I perform test again and again then sometimes i started getting  result of hcitool con as Master example

> ACL DC:A9:71:8D:2D:C6 handle 43 state 1 lm **MASTER** AUTH ENCRYPT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for couple of days , I have found the solution.

Requirment #1 ->to switch role and make it permanent till next restart.

**

```
hciconfig -a hci0 lm master 
hciconfig -a hcio lp hold
```

**