# Output of 'hcitool con'

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, hci

How do I interpret the output of 'hcitool con'?

```
% hcitool con
Connections:
    < ACL 00:11:22:33:44:55 handle 1 state 1 lm SLAVE AUTH ENCRYPT
```

More specifically, I would need details of the following parts:

**handle**:
This seems to be some enumeration of connections, but can I be confident that a new connection always get the lowest free 'handle' number? Does 'handle 0' indicate ongoing connection?

**state**:
That are the states and which numbers are they associated with? I've seen 1, 5, 8, and 9.

**SLAVE**:
Does this mean that the remote device is slave? Or the local?

This question is more or less stated (but not answered) here: [Need detail explanation of Bluetooth command "hcitool con" and hcitool sr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896646/need-detail-explanation-of-bluetooth-command-hcitool-con-and-hcitool-sr)

Answer (score 1):

`hcitool` was [deprecated by the BlueZ project](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) in 2017. If you are following a tutorial that uses it, there is a chance that it might be out of date.

`bluetoothctl` is the command line tool that should be used for connecting to remote devices.

There is also the `btmgmt` tool where you can can get information on the current connection with `sudo btmgmt con`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I work in an environment that doesn't provide btmgmt (bluetoothctl exists, though). Is there any other way to get connection information?

Comment: What information is it that you are after?

Comment: Most of all, I would like to know what hcidump con 'states' indicates. It seems like 'state 1' is successful connection, but I don't know the others.

Comment: The current replacement for `hcidump` is `btmon`. Does that give any better information? You can also output `btmon` to a file and open it in wireshark